# SSH Protocol error: Server and client capabilities don't match

Tags: linux, qt, ssh, qt-creator

I am facing an issue in deploying my Qt GUI executable on to the iMx6 target. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on VMWare, and launching the Qt executable using Qt Creator 3.1.2 (running Qt 5.3.1 cross compiled for iMx6 platform). The error message displayed was:

```
19:08:58: Could not connect to host: SSH Protocol error: Server and client capabilities don't match. Client list was: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss.
Server list was ecdsa-sha2-nistp256.
Is the device connected and set up for network access?
19:08:58: Deploy step failed.
Error while building/deploying project qtGUI (kit: Target)
When executing step 'Check for free disk space'
19:08:58: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

It is purely some problem related to network connection ? or something that am missing here ?

Any help is appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server just allows certificates using ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, while your client just allows ssh-rsa and ssh-dss. Since there is no match between both lists, its not possible to connect to the server.

Your server wants to exchange keys explicitly using Elliptic Curve nistp256. Your client does not know about this method, therefor denies the key-exchange. you will have to update your client SSH certification methods (update ssh clientlibrary) or set your server to allow other certification methods.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I wanted to connect to the board PicoCOMA9X (NXP i.MX6) through SSH in Qt creator and could solve it in the following way:

- Delete all of host keys generate in your board. They are usually located in `/etc/ssh`. You can use `rm ssh_host_*`.
- Restart the ssh session by using `/etc/init.d/S50sshd restart`.

Then check the IP, username and password of the board in Qt, and test the connection.